# How do I log out of Google Chrome on a shared computer?

Tags: google-chrome, multiple-users

I share my computer with someone who does not have a google account, I do not want them to be able to click on chrome and potentially access my saved data (ie. passwords/CC info).  Everytime I attempt to logoff chrome (not my email, chrome itself), I only get the option to delete or change user.  I just want my info off, do I have to delete my account each time or is there a way to just log my infomation off chrome?

Comment: It seems like this is a perfect use case for Incognito Mode.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE (11-Sep-2015): To be able to sign out an account, you need to set up at least one supervised account in Google Chrome (it can be even an account you never use). Once there's a supervised account, you can sign out of ANY account set up in your Chrome.

EARLIER, DOESNT WORK NOW: A sign out feature has been recently implemented, and works properly with Version 34 and later (locks profile; asks for password; unlocks with your Google Account password).

You need to "Enable new profile management system" under `chrome://flags/#enable-new-profile-management` and restart Chrome. Now, when you click on your profile name in the top right corner of Chrome, there's "Lock" link showing next to your avatar. It prevents other users to switch to your account without entering your password, while also keeps local copy of your profile without need to re-populate it from the scratch every time you switch to your user profile.

The only thing to remember is to Lock your profile every time you leave the shared PC. I'm not aware of any auto-lock feature implemented so far.

Comment: This feature seems to have disappeared in later versions. It doesn't matter what value I set the flag to, it still won't show a lock. :(

Comment: Just updated my answer with how it works now in stable Google Chrome. @Hjulle

Comment: Latest version of Chrome keeps Google Account credentials unless you explicitly sign out. This is as worse as it gets.

Comment: It doesn't even logout when removing all browser data under history. (Even in advanced > all checkboxes checked)

Answer (score 2):

First you go to the option on the top right corner, that just looks like 3 parallel lines. Click that, then choose the option 'Signed in as 'your account'" then that will open to a new page. on the newly opened page choose the option down near the bottom of the page and choose "delete user" this wont delete the account forever, you can sign in as many times as you want anywhere and just use the same process if you want to "sign out"

Hope this helped :)

Comment: But wouldn't that cause the machine to delete and retrieve all your data whenever you "sign out" and back in?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: You do not give them your password to the computer.

Do not log off from Chrome (or any other programs). Just log off from windows.
The next/other user then enter his or her non-admin username and password and all is fine.

And yes, I know this is not fully the answer you want to get. But it is the right one.

Comment: What if it's in a coffee shop?

Comment: Nobody enters CC info in a coffee shop. But I guess it is a valid Q for much less important information (e.g. facebook accounts) where the danger of theft is not immediately obvious.

Comment: except he specified that its a shared computer.

Comment: Aye. Which I took as a shared computer in a household.

Comment: @raam86 https covers the coffee shop doesn't it?  in addition to separate windows user accounts.  (though of course, in theory if a password to another user account isn't strong and a person using the computer directly, sharing it, knows stuff, they could get it)

Comment: Actually: no. Https is not secure. On a default installation it merely states that **someone** has a certificate claiming to be that person and that the publisher of those certificates is known.  Compare it to checking the passport from someone. He has a paper, stating that he is person X from country Y and country Y is a well known country which you trust. It does not state that the 'passport' was handed over to person X. Merely to someone who paid money and claimed to be X. (and yes, good 'countries'/certificate authorities do check. Sadly not all are good).

Comment: You can have your own user log in , in  a random coffee shop?

Comment: This is the reason users exist. Chrome (and other browsers) associate a profile to the user account on the operating system (you can have secondary profiles, but that's a pain). This is by design. Also, @barlop, if you enter a password on a public computer you're just begging to have your password stolen. Always assume there is *at least* one keylogger on any public computer. HTTPS (SSL) only protects the data in-transit, not at the endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the spanner on the top right

Where it says "signed in as **XYZ@gmail.com**" click

then select "disconnect your google account"

then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> and choose the combination of settings and the time frame required and clear all data

then its done.

alternatively use an incognito session in future

Comment: That button wasn't there last I checked.